# Nivo slider not working

Tags: drupal-7

I went through many tutorials on how to install nivo slider, but none of them worked for me. The images appear one below the other. I don't know where I am going wrong.I was wondering may be if someone has faced the similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: can you post relevant code?

Comment: Matt, I am just trying the basic installation process by installing the modules.

Comment: Show us the related generated HTML and JS.

Comment: When you inspect the page which has nivoslider, does it show any javascript error?

Comment: I can see 2 errors on the page,Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'nivoSlider'. Failed to load resource http://couponcp-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1238/l.js?pid=1238&systemid=13c24b20e0eae2050ddd15f94f1ac4b2&ext=Coupon%20Companion&aoi=1357825314&zoneid=129805&crr=1360862375. Thanks.

Comment: Steve: where can I find the js and html for nivo slider. I am new to this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Aghh, clearing cache did work, sorry for the trouble and thanks for all your help.

Comment: I reinstalled all the modules again, the jquery update must be 1.7 or high, I think this caused the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the cache, and setting the jquery update the jquery version to 1.8 worked. Thanks.